# Ads.txt not getting updated

Tags: blogger, adsense

I am getting "Earnings at risk – You need to fix some ads.txt file issues to avoid severe impact on your revenue." error for my approved blog http://sudipta-deb.in. It's a custom domain from GoDaddy, but hosted in Blogger.

I have added the code in ads.txt and it is working as I can see the code by navigating http://sudipta-deb.in/ads.txt which redirects to https://www.sudipta-deb.in/ads.txt.

Also, custom robots.txt is added with below code -
User-agent: *
Allow: /ads.txt
Disallow: /ads

Any idea why I am still getting the error and also ads are not appearing in my blog? Are they somehow related i.e. ads will not appear unless this issue is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It may take a few days for your changes to be reflected in AdSense. If your site doesn't make many ad requests it may take up to a month. More information on the subject: [Google adsense ads.txt](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7532444)

Answer (score 0):

Usually Ads.txt is crawled every 24-48 hours, Make sure your inventory has good demand or it will take more time.